# scrollIntoView is not scrolling to requested <div> with Submit button onClick

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I've created a Submit button using javascript calls, and when it is clicked I want two things to happen:

1) the form is submitted. This works fine. The form is submitted successfully.

2) the page should scroll to my "map" . This part is not working. The page does not scroll.

No doubt there is something simple here that I'm not understanding. Thanks for any help.

```html
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div id="tooltip" class="tooltip"></div>
<div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
    <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
    <div id="popup-content"></div>
</div>
```

In a separate file:

```js
var submit = document.createElement("input");
submit.type = "button";
submit.id = "submit";
submit.name = "submit";
submit.value = "Submit";
// scroll to "map" <div> upon form submission 
submit.onclick = function() {
    if (!submitForm()) return false;
        document.getElementById("map").scrollIntoView();
    }
buttonDiv.appendChild(submit);
```

Comment: Have you tried with scrollTo()?

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken so far? Have you checked for errors in the developer console?

Comment: what is the return value of the `submitForm` call?

Comment: Korovjov Yes, thanks. scrollTo() does not work either.

Comment: Pointy  There are no errors in the console.log - Bill

Comment: frontendgirl  submitForm() returns true. Also, I've tried reversing the order of the submitForm() and the scrollIntoView lines of code. - Blll